# Sikuli can't tell colors apart

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I'm developing a program with Java and Sikuli and I want to click on a red image with a specific shape that is located on screen.
The problem is that on the screen there is another image with that same shape but different color, blue.

```
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

this.screen.type("C:\\Images\\TestImage.png", "a"); // this is what I'm using.
```

My mouse keeps moving between the two images because it can't tell the difference in color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way Sikuli can make the right choice for you. It can only locate a matching are based on your pattern (color in this case). To work around this issue you should provide some reference points that are unique and can be used to "help" Sikuli find the right match. For example, if the pattern you are interested in is located at the left side of the screen, then you can limit the search to the left side of the screen only. Or if you have a unique visual object in the are of interested you can use it as a pivot and look only around it.

On top of that, if you have few similar items appear in some ordered fashion (one under another for example), you can let Sikuli find all of them, calculate their coordinates and select the object you need based on these coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Searching using color is possible with **Brobot**, a state-based, testable, automation framework for Java. Brobot wraps Sikuli methods and uses Sikuli variables such as Match in its core functionality. Its color methods depend heavily on matrix operations with OpenCV. The [Brobot documentation](https://jspinak.github.io/brobot/) gives more detailed information on the framework. Additionally, there is a page in the documentation specifically for [color searches](https://jspinak.github.io/brobot/docs/introduction/finding-objects/using-color).

## Color Selection Methods

There are 3 methods used to identify which colors to search for.

1. **Color averaging**. The average color of all pixels is determined from all image files (a single Brobot image can contain multiple image files). The range of acceptable colors around the target color can be adjusted, as well as the required size of the color region.
2. **K-Means**. Images that contain a variety of colors are not suitable to color averaging. The k-Means method from OpenCV finds the salient colors in an image, which are then used in the search. Adjustable options include the number of k-Means, acceptable color range, and required size.
3. **Histogram**. Brobot divides images into 5 regions (4 corners + the middle region) in order to preserve some spatial color characteristics (for example, blue sky on the top of an image will not match blue sea on the bottom of an image). The search can be adjusted by color range, as well as the number of histogram bins for hue, saturation, and value.

## Chained Find Operations

Each of these color methods can be used independently or combined with the traditional Sikuli pattern searches by chaining find operations together. There are two main flavors of chained find operations:

1. **Nested finds**. Matches are searched for inside the matches from the previous find operation. The last find operation is responsible for providing the function’s return value.
2. **Confirmed finds**. The matches from the first find operation are filtered by the results of following find operations. The later find operations act as confirmation or rejection of the initial matches. Confirmed matches from the first find operation are returned.

[Documentation for nested finds and confirmed finds](https://jspinak.github.io/brobot/docs/introduction/finding-objects/combining-finds)

## Finding the Red Image

For your specific question, it would be best to use a chain of two find operations, set up as a *confirmed find*. The first operation would be a pattern search (equivalent to findAll in Sikuli) and the second operation, the confirmation operation, would be a color search.

Actions in Brobot are built with:

1. The action configuration (an ActionOptions variable)
2. The objects to act on (images, regions, locations, etc.)

Brobot encourages defining states with a collection of images that belong together. The code below assumes you have a state StateWithRedImage that contains the image RedImage. The results are returned in a Matches object, which contains information about the matches and the action performed.

```
public class RedImageFinder {

    private final Action action;
    private final StateWithRedImage stateWithRedImage;

    public RedImageFinder(Action action, StateWithRedImage stateWithRedImage) {
        this.action = action;
        this.stateWithRedImage = stateWithRedImage;
    }

    public Matches find() {
        ActionOptions actionOptions = new ActionOptions.Builder()
                .setAction(ActionOptions.Action.FIND)
                .setFind(ActionOptions.Find.ALL)
                .addFind(ActionOptions.Find.COLOR)
                .keepLargerMatches(true)
                .build();
        return action.perform(actionOptions, stateWithRedImage.getRedImage());
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the developer of Brobot. It's free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might help. Create a Region and try to find the image in that region as in example in the link 
http://seleniumqg.blogspot.com/2017/06/findfailed-exception-in-sikuili-script.html?m=1